# In laravel after logged in both guest and user are displayed in navbar?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I try to login. After successful login there was a problem in my navbar

I tried it below for checking

```
@auth('user')
Logged in as a user
@endauth
@guest
You are a guest
@endguest
```

Both are visible in my navbar.
Please help to solve this issue.
I need to make guest as false after successful login

Comment: When using `@auth('user')`, `@guest` should be `@guest('user')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#if-statements

Answer (score 0):

you can use if statement

```
@if(Auth::User())
  Logged in as a user
@else
  You are a guest
@endif
```